# Problems with jQuery/AJAX interaction

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've been studyiing jQuery lately and today I was working with AJAX. What I want to do, right now, is simply send a date from a date picker to a PHP page which sends back that date.
I'll later improve the PHP page to do what I need to do.
Here's the code of the HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="generator" content="AlterVista - Editor HTML"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#foo").submit(function(){
            var serializedData = $(this).serialize();
            $.post('demo.php', serializedData, function(response) {
                // Log the response to the console
                console.log("Response: "+response);
                $("#result").text() = response;
            });
        });
    });
  </script>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id='foo'>
        <input type='date' id='dataI' name='dataI'>
        <input type='submit' value='send'>
        <p id='result'></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the simple php page I made:

```
<?php
    echo $_POST["dataS"];
?>
```

But when I try to send data nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? I tried using a solution I saw here on stack overflow but it doesn't work.

Comment: There's any number of reasons this could be failing. Check the network tab of the console to see what the state of the request is

Answer (score 0):

I am attaching code sample;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="generator" content="AlterVista - Editor HTML"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function validate(){
  
  var serializedData = $('#foo').serialize();
            $.post('ajax.php', serializedData, function(response) {
                // Log the response to the console
                console.log("Response: "+response);
                $("#result").html(response);
            });
return false;

 }
  </script>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id='foo' action="#" onsubmit="return validate()">
        <input type='date' id='dataI' name='dataI'>
        <input type='submit' value='send'>
        <p id='result'></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Ajax code file;

```
 echo $_POST["dataI"];
```

Comment: and in ajax file correct field name like "dataI" not  "dataS"

Answer (score -1):

Try adding return false; after

```
$.post('demo.php', serializedData, function(response) {
            // Log the response to the console
            console.log("Response: "+response);
            $("#result").text() = response;
        });
```

statement.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#foo").submit(function(){
            var serializedData = $(this).serialize();
            $.post('demo.php', serializedData, function(response) {
                // Log the response to the console
                console.log("Response: "+response);
                $("#result").text() = response;
            });
             return false;
            });
        });
```